# Low desktop performance with netbook

Tags: performance, ubuntu-netbook

After installing latest ubuntu on my netbook (ASUS 1225c) I experienced major drop in responsiveness and frames per second on desktop. It seems that there is something wrong with video drivers. The screen updates really slow, especially when trying to move windows or terminal or trying to input some text. I did not have the same problem when installing the system, in fact, everything ran very smooth.
This seems strange, because the netbook is shipped with Ubuntu installed on it.

```
glxinfo | grep renderer
```

returned

```
GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
```

After installing KDE, the problem is gone. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can you post the output of `glxinfo | grep renderer` by appending it to your question?  You may need to `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` first.

Comment: Performance is always somewhat subjective and netbooks are not "performance" machines, they are light weight and low on power. With that in mind, my guess is that it is related to the video card and you are likely to notice the gnome and unity are slower then kde, xfce, or lxde

Comment: The trouble is, that the frame rate is so low that it is impossible to use the system. That is the trouble.

Comment: And now Ubuntu refuses to connect to my Wifi, it just keeps asking for password over and over. I turned the password protection off, and Ubuntu doesn't connect this way either. There is an error popup that says "Disconnected - You are now in offline". Suspending the system and then going back in solved the issue.

Comment: What video chip are you using? `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: @MokonaModoki You are using your CPU for the openGL rendering - this is one of the reasons that your computer feels slow.  Try loading the nonfree firmware:  `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`, reboot, and repeat the `glxinfo | grep renderer` and lets see if the system has detected your video card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To minimize your video incongruity, you can install another graphical interface.

I recommend KDE or MATE for beautiful graphics, and LDXE or Razor-Qt for better performance.

In your terminal use:

#### KDE:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

#### MATE: (for programs belong family GNOME)

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-archive-keyring
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-core
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment
```

#### LXDE: (for programs belong family GNOME)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

#### Razor-Qt: (for programs belong family KDE)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:razor-qt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install razorqt
```

Restart your system.

Comment: I used installed KDE with first 2 lines and restarted my computer. When starting up, there was a "Kubuntu" text, but after startup I saw exactly the same Ubuntu desktop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to select KDE at the long in screen (rather then Unity)

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is with your video card, it does not do 3d graphics. To compensate it uses llvm which uses your CPU rather then your video card to do 3d rendering. The result is your display is slow. Previous versions of unity and gnome did had a 2d fall back mode, but they have been phased out.

"gnome" - both gnome shell and unity - use llvm (llvmpipe) and both will be slow.

Personally, I use KDE which is a balance of eye candy and speed. Other options are xfce or lxde.

kde (kubuntu) is a great spin, xubuntu, and lubuntu will all perform more reasonable for you and none use llvm (llvmpipe).

See http://www.mesa3d.org/llvmpipe.html